# How to select <li> in nested list

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Is there a simple selector expression to not select elements with a specific class?

I want a hover event when hover `<li>` which contain `<small>` tag.

Js code:

```
 $("sidebar-menu li:not(.header)").hover(function () {
    $('.sidebar-menu li a small').show();
}, function () {
    $('.sidebar-menu li a small').hide();
});
```

HTML code:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
                <li class="header la-one">My Page</li><li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-info"></i> <span>Cook<small class="label pull-right bg-yellow" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='https://www.example.com/';" return="" false;'="">-</small></span></li>
    <li class="treeview">
        <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-folder"></i> <span>Other</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
        </a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu">
        <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Service<small class="label pull-right bg-green " onclick="javascript:window.location.href='https://www.exaple.com/'; return false;">+</small></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Enroll<small class="label pull-right bg-green " onclick="javascript:window.location.href='https://www.exaple.tw/'; return false;">+</small></li>

        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i>Portal Ask<small class="label pull-right bg-green " onclick="javascript:window.location.href='https://www.exaple.tw/'; return false;">+</small></a></li>
        </ul>
     </li></ul>
```

UPDATE
 `$("sidebar-menu li:not(.'header')")` to `$("sidebar-menu li:not(.header)")` still trigger event when I hover `<li class="treeview">` and `<li class="header la-one">`.

How can I set the selector which li has `<small>` tag not the others? THX~

Comment: `$(".sidebar-menu li:not(.header)")` add `.` before the `sidebar-menu` class and use not class like this `:not(.header)` .. I recommend to read about selectors [Here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error on onclick line you can notice it [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/saqm0z36/2/) with the red color

`<li class="header la-one">My Page</li><li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-circle-o text-info"></i> <span>Cook<small class="label pull-right bg-yellow" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='https://www.yzu.edu.tw/';" return="" false;'="">`

As I pointed in comment

`$(".sidebar-menu li:not(.header)")`

add `.` before the `sidebar-menu` class and use not class like this `:not(.header)`

I recommend to read about selectors [**Here**](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

[**Working demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/saqm0z36/)

and you can use `:has(small)` as well

`$(".sidebar-menu li:has(small)")`

Answer (score 1):

Heads up!

The error is here: `$(".sidebar-menu li:not(.'header')")` (the single quotes around the *header* selector).

You should simply use `$(".sidebar-menu li:not(.header)")` (without any quote around the *header* selector just as pointed in the comment below your post).

Based on your update, this is what you need:

```
$('.sidebar-menu').find('li:not(.header)').hover(function(){
    console.log('hovered');
    // run your function here (example: $('.sidebar-menu li a small').show();)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To select elements with specific child elements :has selector can be used as given in http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/ & :not for selecting elements without a class.

```
$('li:has(span)').hover(function(){
    // Your hover function
}
```